# Alterar um component Class React para um hook useState React-native

Tags: classes, react-native, react-hooks, component

Quero transformar esse código de `class` em um código de `useState hook`, queria que a mesma funcionalidade que esse código `class` tem passasse a ser a do `Hook`

```
export default class App extends Component { constructor(props) {
  super(props); this.state = {
      selectedStartDate: null, selectedEndDate: null,
  };

  this.onDateChange = this.onDateChange.bind(this);
  }


  onDateChange(date, type){
     if (type === 'END_DATE') {
  this.setState({ 
    selectedEndDate: date,
  });

  } else { this.setState({

    selectedStartDate: date, 
    selectedEndDate: null,
  });
 }
}


render() {

   const { selectedStartDate, selectedEndDate } = this.state;  
   const startDate  =  selectedStartDate ? selectedStartDate.toString() : '';
   const endDate = selectedEndDate ? selectedEndDate.toString() : '';
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>      
     <CalendarPicker 
        startFromMonday={true} 
        allowRangeSelection={true} 
        selectedDayColor="#BA55D3"
        selectedDayTextColor="#000000"     
        selectedDayStyle="#FFF000"
        todayBackgroundColor="#f22465" 
        selectedDayColor="#8df252" 
        selectedDayTextColor="#0f0f0f" 
        onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
     />
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como faço para alterar um Component React para uma função React Hooks?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/480480/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-alterar-um-component-react-para-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-react-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App (props) {
  this.state = {
      selectedStartDate: null, selectedEndDate: null,
  };
  
  const [selectedStartDate, setSelectedStartDate] = useState(null);
  const [selectedEndDate, setSelectedEndDate] = useState(null);


  function onDateChange(date, type){
     if (type === 'END_DATE') {
        setSelectedEndDate(date);
     } else {
        setSelectedStartDate(date)
        setSelectedEndDate(null)
     }
  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>      
    <CalendarPicker 
      startFromMonday={true} 
      allowRangeSelection={true} 
      selectedDayColor="#BA55D3"
      selectedDayTextColor="#000000"     
      selectedDayStyle="#FFF000"
      todayBackgroundColor="#f22465" 
      selectedDayColor="#8df252" 
      selectedDayTextColor="#0f0f0f" 
      onDateChange={onDateChange}
    />
  )
}
```